# Unable to access smarty with php on my local Xampp server

Tags: php, smarty

I've a website which is developed in smarty with php. I've tried this on my local server with php 7.x version & php 5.6. website front page is opening in php 5.6 but when I'm trying to access another page, it shows me an error 404 not found.

I've already updated the config.ini file and config file also. But I'm still unable to access. I've also tried to access these on a live server with different version of php but still no luck.

I'm sharing my config.ini & .htaccess. please help e with this because I've been stuck here for two days

config.ini

```
;admin

[entorno]
desarrollo = false

[general]
charset = utf-8;
urlbase = http://localhost/projects6/stackpro/
pathbase = D:/xampp/htdocs/projects6/stackpro/
ip = 127.0.0.1
name = 'stackpro'
email = stackpro@example.com
langs = es,en,it
lang_default = es
description = 'Plataforma de transacciones de materiales y servicios'
keywords =
analytics = UA-xxxxxxx-x
timezone = Europe/Madrid

[base_de_datos]
db.host = localhost
db.user = root
db.pass = 
db.name = bidline
db.limit = 1000

[App]
class.default = main
page.404 = errorpage
maxfilesize = 209715200
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes


ErrorDocument  404  /404/
RewriteRule ^404/$ /index.php?uno=errorpage

RewriteRule .*\.(ini)$ http://localhost/projects6/stackpro/ [R,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^cfw$ http://localhost/projects6/stackpro/ [R,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^uploads/* http://localhost/projects6/stackpro/ [R,NC,L]


<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>


RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=$1&dos=$2&tres=$3&cuatro=$4
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=$1&dos=$2&tres=$3&cuatro=$4
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=$1&dos=$2&tres=$3
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=$1&dos=$2&tres=$3
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=$1&dos=$2
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=$1&dos=$2
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) /index.php?uno=$1
RewriteRule ^admin /index.php


RewriteRule ^login/logout/ /index.php?uno=login&dos=logout
RewriteRule ^login/logout /index.php?uno=login&dos=logout
RewriteRule ^login/register/ /index.php?uno=login&dos=register
RewriteRule ^login/register /index.php?uno=login&dos=register
RewriteRule ^login/restorepassword/ /index.php?uno=login&dos=restorepassword
RewriteRule ^login/restorepassword /index.php?uno=login&dos=restorepassword
RewriteRule ^login/ /index.php?uno=login
RewriteRule ^login /index.php?uno=login


RewriteRule ^aboutus/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=main&dos=aboutus&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^aboutus/(.*) /index.php?uno=main&dos=aboutus&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^aboutus/ /index.php?uno=main&dos=aboutus
RewriteRule ^aboutus /index.php?uno=main&dos=aboutus


RewriteRule ^personascontacto/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=personascontacto&tres=$1&cuatro=$2
RewriteRule ^personascontacto/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=personascontacto&tres=$1&cuatro=$2
RewriteRule ^personascontacto/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=personascontacto&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^personascontacto/(.*) /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=personascontacto&tres=$1

RewriteRule ^delegaciones/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=delegaciones&tres=$1&cuatro=$2
RewriteRule ^delegaciones/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=delegaciones&tres=$1&cuatro=$2
RewriteRule ^delegaciones/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=delegaciones&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^delegaciones/(.*) /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=delegaciones&tres=$1

RewriteRule ^account/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^account/(.*) /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^account/ /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=$1
RewriteRule ^account /index.php?uno=cuenta&dos=$1


RewriteRule ^compras/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=compras&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^compras/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=compras&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^compras/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=compras&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^compras/(.*) /index.php?uno=compras&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^compras/ /index.php?uno=compras&dos=$1
RewriteRule ^compras /index.php?uno=compras&dos=$1


RewriteRule ^ventas/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=ventas&dos=$1&tres=$2&cuatro=$3
RewriteRule ^ventas/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=ventas&dos=$1&tres=$2&cuatro=$3
RewriteRule ^ventas/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=ventas&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^ventas/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=ventas&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^ventas/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=ventas&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^ventas/(.*) /index.php?uno=ventas&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^ventas/ /index.php?uno=ventas&dos=$1
RewriteRule ^ventas /index.php?uno=ventas&dos=$1

RewriteRule ^comentarios/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=comentarios&dos=init&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^comentarios/(.*) /index.php?uno=comentarios&dos=init&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^comentarios/ /index.php?uno=comentarios&dos=init&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^comentarios /index.php?uno=comentarios&dos=init&tres=$1

RewriteRule ^contacto/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=contacto&dos=init&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^contacto/(.*) /index.php?uno=contacto&dos=init&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^contacto/ /index.php?uno=contacto&dos=init&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^contacto /index.php?uno=contacto&dos=init&tres=$1


RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=ajax&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=ajax&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=ajax&dos=$1
RewriteRule ^ajax/(.*) /index.php?uno=ajax&dos=$1


RewriteRule ^lang/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=main&dos=lang&tres=$1
RewriteRule ^lang/(.*) /index.php?uno=main&dos=lang&tres=$1


RewriteRule ^files/(.*)/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=files&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)/(.*) /index.php?uno=files&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)/ /index.php?uno=files&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^files/(.*) /index.php?uno=files&dos=$1&tres=$2
RewriteRule ^files/ /index.php?uno=files&dos=$1
RewriteRule ^files /index.php?uno=files&dos=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue of php version.

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating virtual host of your project,it treat your site like hosted web application